# Pagination error while using datatable

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination, datatables

i am using jquery datatable plugin. its working fine except for the pagination part.its showing 1 to 10 records(filtered from 22000 records).since there is only 10 records the next and back buttons are not working

the following is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').dataTable( {

    "bProcessing": "true",
    "bServerSide": "true",
    "bPaginate": "true",
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "sAjaxSource": "ailsdsw.php?b=<?php echo $_SESSION['brcd_se32'] ?>";


} );
} );
```

the json ouput is goe like this

```
 {"sEcho":0,"iTotalRecords":"22289","iTotalDisplayRecords":"22289","aaData":[["301","1","40353",....]]}
```

can someone explain me why the pagination is not working

Answer (score 0):

The totals should be ints.  Try w/o the strings in your JSON around the values:

```
"iTotalRecords":22289, "iTotalDisplayRecords":22289
```

> int   iTotalRecords   Total records, before filtering (i.e. the total
>   number of records in the database)
>
> int   iTotalDisplayRecords    Total records, after filtering (i.e. the
>   total number of records after filtering has been applied - not just
>   the number of records being returned in this result set)